# Response code 411 mapped as failure

Tags: response

when Im trying to run my flow, getting this

```
error Response code 411 mapped as failure Response code 411 mapped as failure.
Payload               : org.glassfish.grizzly.utils.BufferInputStream@16e8c87
Element               : /post_sampleFlow/processors/1 @ post_sample:post_sample.xml:70 (HTTP_Post).
```

please tell me what is the problem.

Comment: Please provide more information...

Comment: i just want to get access token. can u please guide me how to get that?

Comment: You are using post_sampleFlow, so I expect that it is POST method processing, 411 means that length is needed. Please provide `Content-Length` in your header. Use postman or some other tool, and that will be there. However, to me it looks like you are doing something wrong, and from that point - I need to know more to give you good answer...

Comment: actually Im trying to give form data in mule using post method? bt i dnt know how to do it in mule. so im trying using http connector... if you know anything about it please guide me..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920203/mule-esb-how-to-create-a-http-request-with-post-method-sending-parameters-alo - is this the answer?

Comment: No. my question is we can give form data in postman using post method and get the access token in response. same I want to do in mule. but in mule we do not have any form data option so how can we provide the client id and secret as a form data and get the access token in response?

Comment: can you please edit this question? add mule tag, and change title to reflect that it is about sending request from mule flow to auth user? That will give you less -1... I've tried to do that, by my changes ware rejected...

Answer (score 0):

So problem is how to use mule to auth user.

From this [doc](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.5/property-transformer-reference):

```
<set-property propertyName="Authorization"  doc:name="Set Authentication Header" value="#["Basic " + Base64.encodeBase64String("username:password")]"/>
```

So, that way all properties can be filled.

BTW now I see need for that flows.